# Schematic Explanation

Tags: power, circuit-analysis, analog, schematics, buck-boost

Could someone please explain to me in as much detail as possible the schematic below. I'm really confused and would appreciate someone walking me through this.

What is the Rationale of connecting the componenets the way they are:

- Why is there a resistor across the transformer secondary pins?
- Why  are there two bjt's connected to each other?
- why a zener and a diode in series?
- what is the purpose of those 4 MOSFETs?
- why are the 4 bridge MOSFETS are connected by an inductor?
- why is there a mosfet connected to the right and left of the low side fets and the highside FETs?

[image]

Comment: Can you be specific? What do you already know about this circuit? What parts can you understand on your own? What parts do you particularly want an explanation of?

Comment: yeah, I mean, it is a buck-boost converter, like it says in the top left corner, large letters. So, do you understand buck-boost converters? If not, this is the time to research them, and with your newfound knowledge, re-assess the schematic. Like it is stated now, this is simply far too broad – you don't even tell us what you *do* understand! So, we can't know whether we need to tell you how a diode works, or whether you need a high-level behaviour description. So, voting to close as "in need of focus", I'm afraid.

Comment: Literally everything beyond the transformer. Why is there a resistor across the transformer secondary pins, Why are there two bjt's in series, why a zener and a diode in series, what is the purpose of those 4 mosfets, why are they connected by an inductor, why is there a mosfet connected to the right and left of the low side fets and the high side fets

Comment: Where are there two BJT's in series? BJTs are 3-terminal elements so it doesn't even make sense to say they're in series with anything. Beyond that, please **edit your question** to clarify what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I edited the question to clarify further !

Comment: That's now **seven** questions in one. That's still too broad; you're asking about twigs on trees, but don't understand how the forest works. This schematic is pretty much meaningless until you full understand what an H-Bridge is (that's the one thing one instantly thinks when one sees four MOSFETs and has dealt with power supplies before), and how a few classical switch-mode power supply architectures work. We can't write an answer that describes every single one of these components in limited time. I recommend you really first take to a good book about switch-mode supply design,and then ask.

Answer (score 1):

That is the power section of a high power switching regulator, of a type called buck-boost.  The input voltage can be above, equal to, or below the output voltage.  Linear Technology (now a part of analog Devices) has a line of control chips for this.  Here is one, and the datasheet has a good applications section.

https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ltc3779.pdf

Comment: This isnt' a complete regulator. It's basically an H-bridge and an inductor. There's no control functions at all, just off-sheet connectors where the control signals are meant to come from.

Comment: Edited. word word